# Binding from code to a custom attached property in WinRT/UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying to create a binding from code in a library that targets multiple frameworks (WPF, WinRT, UWP etc), and I'm hitting a brick wall. The property I'm trying to bind to is a *custom* attached property. In WPF, I can pass the `DependencyProperty` itself as the binding path:

```
new PropertyPath(MyClass.MyAttachedProperty)
```

But in WinRT the `PropertyPath` class only accepts a string. I tried to pass the name of the property like this:

```
new PropertyPath("(MyClass.MyAttachedProperty)")
```

but of course it doesn't work, since my class is not in the default namespace. In XAML I could map the namespace to a prefix and use that prefix, but as far as I know it's not possible to do this from code.

Is there any way to create this binding in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, after researching and discussing we've confirmed that in UWP, we cannot programmatically binding to custom attached property. Sadly.

You may submit a request to add this new features for development through the Windows Feedback tool.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, you're welcome, sorry I couldn't help much.

Comment: It's OK, I found another way to do what I wanted. I posted a suggestion with the feedback app.

Comment: First thing I was trying to do something with UWP. whoops. I was trying to bind the attached property Left of a canvas to a propdp.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though there may be a solution here, which involves using XamlReader.Load and a resource dictionary containing the binding, to get the loader to do the work for you.

[How can I bind to a custom attached property in c# from code behind in a windows store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287091/how-can-i-bind-to-a-custom-attached-property-in-c-sharp-from-code-behind-in-a-wi/47762610#47762610)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I no longer need this, but I'll keep it in mind